# az acr build fails because of access to file he does not need

Tags: .net, windows, azure, docker, acr

I'm building manually docker images from .NET 6 projects on Windows and uploading them to a docker container registry in Azure.

I'm in the folder with the dockerfile and run:

```
az acr build --registry MyContainerRegistry --image project/imagename:v1 .
```

And receive the following error message:

```
Packing source code into tar to upload...
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '.\\some_directory_hierarchy\\obj\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\OneOfMyProjects.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'
```

The dockerfile has no reference to this file, and AFAIK editorconfig isn't needed in the build process. From the first line, I can tell that no step defined in the docker file is run.

Just to highlight:

- I am logged in to Azure
- The same way I'm doing it worked with multiple docker images in the same project when uploading to the same registry.
- When using `docker build` on the same dockerfile the process runs and finishes successfully.

Why `az acr build` does not work?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the build process is attempting to include a file (`OneOfMyProjects.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig`) in the source code tarball that might not be necessary for the Docker build.

- You can use a `.dockerignore` file to exclude unnecessary files or directories. Create a file named `.dockerignore` in the same directory as your Dockerfile and list files or patterns to exclude

Here, I have a `image` in my ACR pushed from my Docker desktop. After the above changes, I can run the `az acr build` as expected.

[image]

- Run the command - **`az acr build --registry testregdec7 --image my-sample-app .`**

[image]

[image]